# Ruby array of arrays and nil guard

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have the following code

```
class Room
  attr_reader :content, :descr
  def initialize
    @content     = get_content
    @descr       = get_description
  end

  def get_content
    ['errors', 'bugs', 'syntax problems'].sample
  end

  def get_description
    "This room has #{self.content}"
  end
end

@rooms = Array.new(3, Array.new(3))
@rooms[1][1] ||= Room.new 
# => #<Room:0x68985d8 @content="errors", @descr="This room has errors">

p @rooms # =>
#[[nil, #<Room:0x68985d8 @content="errors", @descr="This room has errors">, nil],
# [nil, #<Room:0x68985d8 @content="errors", @descr="This room has errors">, nil],
# [nil, #<Room:0x68985d8 @content="errors", @descr="This room has errors">, nil]]


@rooms = Array.new(3, Array.new(3))
@rooms[1][2] ||= Room.new
# => #<Room:0x6aaab58 @content="bugs", @description="This room contains bugs">

p @rooms # =>
#[[nil, nil, #<Room:0x6aaab58 @content="bugs", @descr="This room has bugs">],
# [nil, nil, #<Room:0x6aaab58 @content="bugs", @descr="This room has bugs">],
# [nil, nil, #<Room:0x6aaab58 @content="bugs", @descr="This room has bugs">]]
```

It's supposed to create a new `Room` instance in one place (if it doesn't exist yet), not in the entire column at once. Instead of creating said instance in `[1][1]` or wherever, it's being set for `[0][2]`, `[1][2]` and `[2][2]`.

Why is that so?  How can I change it to work correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I struggled on this recently, you have to change this line `@rooms = Array.new(3, Array.new(3))` into:

```
@rooms = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
```

What happens in the former is that the argument `Array.new(3)` gets evaluated and creates a new array of 3 elements (I'll call it `a`). Then, doing `Array.new(3, a)` creates a new array of 3 elements, all elements containing `a`.

And `a` is a mutable object, so when you modify it for one column all the columns are modified.

In the solution, the block `{ Array.new(3) }` is evaluated for each element, that's why each column is a different array.

Comment: Well, that would've probably caused me to throw my keyboard through the window if I didn't ask and tried to play with it by myself. Thank you!

Comment: I know the feeling, no problem.

Comment: Just to clarify here, being "a mutable object" isn't exactly the problem. It's that the same object reference is saved in every array slot. Look at the difference between `Array.new(3, Array.new).map(&:object_id)` and `Array.new(3) { Array.new }.map(&:object_id)`.

Comment: Yes, but if the object were to be immutable, then modifying it would not alter the others.

Comment: @blob, you should not play with your keyboard. You might damage it.

Comment: @blob: BTW, your *exact* problem is *explicitly* mentioned in [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas), including the solution. Although re-written and improved several times, that example has been in there since RDoc comments were first added to MRI in 2003. It's also a duplicate that has been asked multiple times already on [so].

Comment: @JörgWMittag well, now I feel kinda bad. Not sure why it didn't occur to me to look up the docs for the exact code I was using, but I'll probably will the next time I hit something similar.